# I want to append data in existing file via Client server Socket in Java

Tags: java

Here Client Module

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Socket smtpSocket = null;  
        DataOutputStream os = null;
        DataInputStream is = null;
        String strout;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            smtpSocket = new Socket("localhost", 55);
            os = new DataOutputStream(smtpSocket.getOutputStream());
            is = new DataInputStream(smtpSocket.getInputStream());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: hostname");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: hostname");
        }

    if (smtpSocket != null && os != null && is != null) {
            try {
                do{
                    System.out.print("Write what the client will send: ");

                strout = in.nextLine();
                os.writeBytes(strout);
                }
                while(!strout.equals("exit"));
                os.close();
                is.close();
                smtpSocket.close();  
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                System.err.println("Trying to connect to unknown host: " + e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
            }
        }
    }           
};
```

Here Server Module

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
         BufferedWriter out;
         ServerSocket echoServer = null;
            String line;
            DataInputStream is;
            PrintStream os;
            Socket clientSocket = null;

    // Try to open a server socket on port 9999
           try {
               echoServer = new ServerSocket(55);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
               System.out.println(e);
            }   
    // Create a socket object from the ServerSocket to listen and accept 
    // connections.
    // Open input and output streams

           try {
               clientSocket = echoServer.accept();
               is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
               InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(is);
               BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);
               os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
               out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C://Users//Muhammad//workspace//New//file.txt"));
               // As long as we receive data, echo that data back to the client.

               while (true) {
                   line = br.readLine();
                   System.out.println(line);
                   os.println(line);
                   os.flush();
                   if( line != null ){
                    out.write(line + '\n');
                    out.flush();
                   }
               }
           }
    catch (IOException e) {
               System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Kindly help me out. How can i append dta in existing file even before data not remove it.

for Example:
i have write first
e.g hi how are you?
and i close the program. and when i start again and write some thing new like:
e.g i have done my work
so, when i will open my that store file and previous data and current data both are shown like
e.g hi how are you? i have done my work.

Comment: Kindly help me out one thing more how can i delete some data in existing file in above code

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FileWriter constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) with append mode to append file instead of re-writing. So change this:

```
out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C://Users//Muhammad//workspace//New//file.txt"));
```

to

```
out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C://Users//Muhammad//workspace//New//file.txt", true));
```

Comment: Kindly help me out one thing more how can i delete some data in existing file in above code

Comment: @Ahmad Don't limit yourself to me for help. Post a new question, there will be plenty of help offered.